# Onblur event fires when clicking on the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, lwc

I have a onblur event on included in the HTML of LWC:

```
onblur={closeDropdown}
```

and here is the closeDropdown in the js file:

```
closeDropdown(event) {
setTimeout( handler: () => {
this.validate()
this.toggleOpenDropDown( toggleState: false)
}, timeout: 200)
}
```

It is supposed to close the dropdown when a user clicks outside the field. The problem is that it also closes the dropdown when you click on the scrollbar to scroll down the list. The onblur event somehow treats the scrollbar as not being part of the field. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: perhaps you could use something like document.activeElement on the blur event and check where the current focus is, if its on the scroll bar, then don't continue. Either that or wrap the whole thing in some sort of container and then el.contains(document.activeElement); to see if the focus is still within the container. Sorry I dont know LWC to be more specific

Comment: @Brad I tried to use document.activeElement in an if else statement: 

`closeDropdown(event) {
if (document.activeElement === scrollbars){}
else{
setTimeout( handler: () => {
this.validate()
this.toggleOpenDropDown( toggleState: false)
}, timeout: 200)}
}`
but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. I just realized you can use `event.preventDefault()` on the `onMouseDown` event. `onMouseDown` will cause a blur event by default. `preventDefault` will stop onBlur from getting invoked. A blur event will still happen, only after `onClick`. (Considering you click outside the div block which has a scrollbar).